# Escaping Angular SPA application on selected set of URLs

Tags: angular, routes, hybrid

Hello Stack Community,

We integrating some external CMS content into already running Angular application. Consider following set of URLs:

- `myAppDomain.com/some/spa/url1`
- `myAppDomain.com/some/spa/url2`
- `myAppDomain.com/some/cms/url`

While both `some/spa/url1` and `some/spa/url2` are standard URLs managed by Angular router, `myAppDomain.com/some/cms/url` shall "escape" SPA application and load CMS content under same url. What are the best technical concepts to make this happen?

Currently, from what I figured out:

Nginx configuration of server that hosts angular app will be modified, to filter all CMS-related requests and via path re-write send them to CMS. That will cover users comming from direct link click (like from email)

But I'm wondering how to gracefully manage users that are already inside app and shall visit CMS page i.e. via some button/link click. Their requests are obviously not sent to nginx backend (as it's SPA), so re-write rules won't apply. In this case I figured out that all CMS pages will have corresponding component in Angular that will handle some brute-force redirection via `window.location.assign`, but I'm sure some way more clever ideas can be found?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using using a typical link to redirect to your non-SPA pages?

So instead of `<a routerLink="/some/cms/url">CMS</a>` use `<a href="/some/cms/url">CMS</a>`